# Replace \s with \s, (space + coma) between to strings in a text file

Tags: regex

I have a file opened with N++. In the file text I need to find the text type

```
<tags="Word1 Word2 Word3">
```

and into this, to replace simple space `\s` between some words with `\s,` (space + coma) and obtain

```
<tags="Word1, Word2, Word3">
```

With regex I used the string

```
(?<=<tags=")(.*?\w)\s*?(?=">)
```

and it works fine to find words, but how to request now to replace `\s` with `\s,` ?

Comment: Language tag please. Regex replacement does not operate in a vacuum.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: no language. A simply xml from one application.

Comment: How many words can fit within the tag?

Comment: **That's *not* XML.**   Removing XML from Q and tagging...

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: the number of words is undefied, maybe 1, 2,... or none

Comment: Also, as others have asked, *what language or application are you using*?   To answer "no language" makes no sense as regex alone doesn't "replace", it *recognizes*.

Comment: @kjhughes regex flavor of Notepad++ I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in one regex however, the following can be repeated until there is no match

Find what

```
<tags="([^"\s]|(?<=,)\s)*+\K(?=\s)
```

Replace with

```
,
```

Comment: Excat, It is not possible, then I performed each case with 2 steps using, in N++, macros. At the beginning I found
    (?<=<tags=")(.*?)(?=">)
then with nect step, in the selected region, I replace \s with ,\s.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing `( )(?=[\w, ]*?">)` with

```
,
```